# How make this filter sargeable or improve index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, sql-execution-plan, postgresql-performance

`vzla_seg` are the road network segments. Each segment have his general azimuth.  `COUNT(*) = 3.849.834`

```
CREATE TABLE vzla_seg (`azimuth` int);

INSERT INTO vzla_seg  (`azimuth`)
VALUES
    (330),    (335),
    (340),    (345),
    (350),    (355),
    (359),    (3),
    (5),      (15),
    (20),     (25),
    (30),     (35)
;
```

Im trying to find segments on the same general direction (+/- 30 degrees) as my parameter `carAzimuth` .

`Azimuth` range is `[0 ..359]` for compass degrees. So if `carAzimuth = 345` is on the same direction as a road segments with azimuth `[315, 325, 359, 0, 5, 15]`

```
carAzimuth = 355
    segmentAzimuth = 340 --> (355 - 340) -->      15  < 30
    segmentAzimuth = 359 --> (355 - 359) --> abs(- 4) < 30       
    segmentAzimuth =  20 --> (355 -  20) -->      25  < 30

carAzimuth = 5
    segmentAzimuth = 340 --> (5 - 340) --> abs(- 335) > 330       
    segmentAzimuth = 359 --> (5 - 359) --> abs(- 354) > 330       
    segmentAzimuth =  20 --> (5 -  20) --> abs(  -15) < 30
```

[image]

```
explain analyze
    SELECT *
    FROM map.vzla_seg S
    WHERE
        abs(carAzimuth - S.azimuth) < 30 
     OR abs(carAzimuth - S.azimuth) > 330
```

**Index:**

```
CREATE INDEX vzla_seg_azimuth_idx
  ON map.vzla_seg
  USING btree
  (azimuth);
```

**Explain Plan:**

```
"Seq Scan on vzla_seg s  (cost=0.00..151243.55 rows=2138790 width=84) 
                         (actual time=0.061..14086.038 rows=690334 loops=1)"
"  Filter: ((abs((345 - azimuth)) < 30) OR (abs((345 - azimuth)) > 330))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 3159500"
"Total runtime: 14283.524 ms"
```

**Bonus question:**

- If explain say `Rows Removed by Filter: 3.159.500` and `rows=690.334` that match total `COUNT(*) = 3.849.834`

  - Why cost say `rows=2.138.790`?

Comment: Paste your `CREATE TABLE` statement and a few `INSERT` statements into your question.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' do you really need `Create Table` what aditional information you want from there, Only one field relevant `azimuth integer`. Maybe `azimuth` isnt a common term?

Comment: Follow the info link in the postgresql-performance tag.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall Again isnt my first question, I just dont see how that can help you to find the answer. If you can be more specific on  how I can improve my question please let me know. Anyway I include the `CREATE TABLE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BETWEEN` and/ or greater than/less than:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM map.vzla_seg S
    WHERE
        (S.azimuth BETWEEN (carAzimuth - 30) AND (carAzimuth + 30))
     OR  S.azimuth  < (carAzimuth - 330) 
     OR  S.azimuth  > (carAzimuth + 330)
```

Comment: `azimuth` range is `0 ... 359` degree, like a circle. So after `359` start with `0` again

Comment: Also `345` is a parameter not a constant, but dont know how add a parameter with the explain :(

Comment: I figured it was, which is why I left the components separate; you can just replace 354 with your parameter name.  Not sure what to do about the resetting angle - in your original query if `carAzimuth` was 359 and `S.azimuth` was 1 you'd get a "difference" of 358, not -2.

Comment: So the math should be the same with this version.  It's just rearranging the `ABS(x-y) < z` to the equivalent `y > z-x OR y < z+x`.  The benefit here is it can pre-calculate `z-x` and `z+x` and use the index on `y` effectively.

Comment: I see, but in this case I have to expand two `abs()` so that mean four `OR`, isnt? I can try that

Comment: Im so embarrassed. You are right, I create one excel table with segment values from `[0 .. 359]`, then a cell to change carAzimuth and all condition match exact as required.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
with param(car_azimuth) as (select 345) 
    select *
    from vzla_seg s, param
    where 
        s.azimuth > car_azimuth- 30 and   
        s.azimuth < car_azimuth+ 30 or
        s.azimuth < car_azimuth- 330 or 
        s.azimuth > car_azimuth+ 330;
```

The plan probably depends on what way the parameter will be passed. Explain with a constant (on 1 million rows):

```
explain 
    select *
    from vzla_seg s
    where 
        s.azimuth > 345- 30 and   
        s.azimuth < 345+ 30 or
        s.azimuth < 345- 330 or 
        s.azimuth > 345+ 330;

                                           QUERY PLAN                                            
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on vzla_seg s  (cost=3496.96..11233.44 rows=160405 width=8)
   Recheck Cond: (((azimuth > 315) AND (azimuth < 375)) OR (azimuth < 15) OR (azimuth > 675))
   ->  BitmapOr  (cost=3496.96..3496.96 rows=165574 width=0)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on vzla_seg_azimuth_idx  (cost=0.00..2598.70 rows=123828 width=0)
               Index Cond: ((azimuth > 315) AND (azimuth < 375))
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on vzla_seg_azimuth_idx  (cost=0.00..773.52 rows=41746 width=0)
               Index Cond: (azimuth < 15)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on vzla_seg_azimuth_idx  (cost=0.00..4.43 rows=1 width=0)
               Index Cond: (azimuth > 675)
(9 rows)
```

Comment: I guess my question wasnt that well written as I tought.  I did another update hopping is clear. For example `s.azimuth > 675` is always false range is [0..359]. Also dont know why only one `AND` doesnt look simetrical. I think cant be done because need a calculation formula depend on `(carAzimuth - roadAzimuth) < 0`, so wont use index.

Comment: This is an arithmetic exact equivalent of your query with `abs`. You can check it on your data. Is your query correct?

Comment: Im so embarrassed. You are right, I create one excel table with segment values from `[0 .. 359]`, then a cell to change carAzimuth and all condition match exact as required. The worst part is your solution is the same as D Stanley and I didnt saw it.

Comment: Q: Is there a way to use explain with variables? Because your first query with cte and parameter doesnt use the index and do a full scan. Anyway the soultion Is ok and I can do the replace for a constant and index work as intented, and that is way will work in the function. But is troublesome change it if want to test it performance with different values.

Comment: Adding a simple cte to a query often makes the planner can't find optimizations. You can test `explain` in psql using its variables. In fact Stanley's query differs from mine only in details, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

See if this makes optimal use of the index:

```
SELECT *
FROM map.vzla_seg S
WHERE s.azimuth > 315 and s.azimuth < 375;
```

If so, then I think the logic is:

```
SELECT *
FROM map.vzla_seg S
WHERE (s.azimuth > 315 and s.azimuth < 375) or
      (s.azimuth > 15 and s.azimuth < 30) ;
```

If this doesn't use the index, use `union all` instead of `or`:

```
SELECT *
FROM map.vzla_seg S
WHERE (s.azimuth > 315 and s.azimuth < 375)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM map.vzla_seg S
WHERE (s.azimuth > 15 and s.azimuth < 30) ;
```

Comment: `azimuth` range is `0 ... 359` degree, like a circle

Comment: Also `345` is a parameter not a constant, but dont know how add a parameter with the explain :(